# IdTCPClient not receiving data anymore

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, firemonkey, tcp

This very simple piece of code was working just fine until a few hours ago.

I'm using a `TTimer` to launch a Write and Read event from the `IdTCPClient` 
component.

Somehow, it is not working anymore. It simply freezes when trying to `ReadLn`.

I suspect that `ReadLn` is blocking the main thread waiting for the server thread to call `WriteLn()`.

```
procedure TFormLogin.TimerGetListTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  genset_response: String;

begin

  TimerGetList.Enabled := false;
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('GET_LIST');
  genset_response := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn();


end;
```

- if I execute `genset_response := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadString(8);` it's possible to get the first 8 letters from the response body.
- if I execute `ShowMessage(IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn('',200));` it returns blank.

### How can I correctly read data from the server without blocking the main thread?

Comment: Move it to a separate thread, like the other dozens of similar questions asked before tell you. Do some research before posting, starting with a simple search here.

Comment: Your symptoms suggest that the server is sending some data, but is not sending a `LF` character. You are indeed blocking the main UI thread while waiting for that character. Using `TIdAntiFreeze` will avoid the UI freeze, but will also cause reenty issues with your timer. Either way, definitely move the code into a worker thread, do not use a timer.

Comment: I'm using FMX. There is no reason to use `TIdAntiFreeze` since it is running on a mobile platform

Comment: Could you please ellaborate how can I move it into a separated thread using mobile? The other dozens of similar questions asked before are mainly recommended to use it inside the `OnExecute` method, which does not exist in `FMX`.